# Problem with 3D plot on using Animate

Tags: plotting, animation

I'm trying to plot the function:

```
f[a_, b_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, s_, k_, \[Phi]_] := -((2 E^((2 k \[Beta]^2 (a^2 + b^2+ 2 \[Alpha]^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] \[Alpha] (a Cos[\[Phi]] +b Sin[\[Phi]])))/(-2 \[Alpha]^2 + (-2 + k s) \[Beta]^2))k \[Beta]^2)/(-2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]^2 + \[Pi] (-2 + k s) \[Beta]^2))
```

I would like to create an animation of this function as I vary the parameter 'k' from 0 to 1 as follows.

```
Animate[Plot3D[f[a, b, 2, 200, 1, k, \[Pi]/2], {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10},PlotRange -> All, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap", #2/10] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {k, 0, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

However, the animation of the 3D plot doesn't show the top most part of the generated surface. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 60 ` ?

Answer (score 2):

> the animation of the 3D plot doesn't show the top most part of the
> generated surface

Add `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`  It was not showing it all before, because default is `Speed`

```
Animate[
 Plot3D[f[a, b, 2, 200, 1, k, \[Pi]/2], {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], 
  Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap", #2/10] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
 {k, 0, 1},
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Compare to what you had

```
Animate[
 Plot3D[f[a, b, 2, 200, 1, k, \[Pi]/2], {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], 
  Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap", #2/10] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
 {k, 0, 1},
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Btw, I think a better animation would be to fix the vertical range. This way you can see better what is going on, and see the context better.

You'd have to run this couple of times first to see what is the maximum range needed, then hardcode this range in. Like this

```
Animate[
 Plot3D[f[a, b, 2, 200, 1, k, \[Pi]/2], {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 0.6}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap", #2/10] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
 {k, 0, 1},
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful.

Comment: +1 The maximum value is `MaxValue[{f[a, b, 2, 200, 1, k, Pi/2], -10 < a < 10,-10 < b < 10, 0 <= k <= 1}, {a, b, k}]` which evaluates to `10000/(5001*Pi)` or `0.636492`